# Which classes stack with others for determining Animal Companion bonuses?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, druid, dnd-3e, animal-companions

What I am looking for is a complete list of every class and prestige class in any of the first party WotC-published D&D 3.0 or 3.5 rulebooks that stacks with other classes in determining the bonuses of an Animal Companion either by increasing effective druid level or otherwise.

I can think of druid, ranger, beastmaster, halfling outrider, wild plains outrider, arcane hierophant, and lion of talisid off the top of my head. I don't think there are a whole lot more than that but I want to be aware of all of them. If there are resources that provide this info, could you point me toward those resources?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posted originally in 2008 on the Wizards of the Coast boards [here](http://community.wizards.com/forum/previous-editions-character-optimization/threads/1068066) and updated in May 2010 on the Minmax Boards [here](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?PHPSESSID=1n2onrs9hd0mad3lg6vvu0t0m0&topic=1412.0), Surreal's List of Stuff, in addition to providing a great deal more, lists classes that improve one's animal companion. I assume--given the amount of research in other areas--that its animal companion information is comprehensive (the absence of the halfling outrider notwithstanding), but it does exclude *Dragon* and *Dungeon* magazines.

Below I've confirmed that the prestige classes do, in fact, advance animal companions as the List of Stuff's commentary is either absent or telegraphic.

**From the List of Stuff**

- The prestige class abolisher (*LoM* 182) at level 1 gains the ability animal companions. It reads, in part,

  > If you have an animal companion, your abolisher levels stack with your previous class levels (usually druid or ranger) to determine the animal companion’s abilities. (183)
- The prestige class arcane hierophant (*RW* 108) at level 1 gains the ability companion familiar. It reads, in part,

  > You add your arcane hierophant class level to your druid or ranger level for purposes of determining your animal companion’s bonus Hit Dice, natural armor adjustment, and Strength/Dexterity adjustment (see the sidebar The Druid’s Animal Companion,
  >   page 36 of the *Player’s Handbook*). [...] You add your arcane hierophant class level to your arcane spellcasting class level, and determine the Intelligence bonus and special abilities of your animal companion accordingly (see the sidebar Familiars, page 53 of the
  >   *Player’s Handbook*).
- The prestige class animal lord (*CAd* 22) at level 1 gains the extraordinary ability animal bond. It reads, in part,

  > If an animal lord has the animal companion class feature, he adds his animal lord level to his effective druid level for the purpose of determining his animal companion’s bonus Hit Dice, special abilities, and so forth. (23)
- The prestige class beastmaster (*CAd* 26) at level 1 gains the extraordinary ability animal companion. It reads, in part,

  > If a beastmaster already has an animal companion from another class, her beastmaster class levels stack with class levels from all other classes that grant an animal companion.
- The prestige class gatekeeper mystagogue (*PE* 87) at level 1 gains the ability animal companion. It reads, in part,

  > If you have an animal companion, your gatekeeper mystagogue levels stack with your previous class levels (usually druid or ranger) to determine the animal companion's abilities. (88)
- The prestige class lion of Talisid (*BE* 65) at level 1 gains the extraordinary ability animal companion. It reads

  > A lion of Talisid can add his lion of Talisid levels to his effective druid level (his actual druid level or one-half his ranger level) to determine the capabilities of his
  >   animal companion. (66)
- The prestige class peregrine runner (*RS* 116)  at level 1 gains the extraordinary ability peregrine companion. It reads, in part,

  > If a character already has a peregrine falcon [that uses the statistics for a hawk (*MM* 273)] animal companion from another class, the levels of that class stack with his peregrine runner class levels to determine the falcon’s power and abilities according to the animal companion table on page 36 of the *Player’s Handbook*. (118)
- The prestige class planar shepherd (*FE* 105) at level 1 gains the ability animal companion. It reads

  > Your planar shepherd levels stack with your druid levels for the purpose of determining
  >   the abilities of your animal companion. (106).
- The prestige class revenant blade (*PE* 142) at level 1 gains the ability ranger class features. This reads, in part,

  > If you have ranger levels, your revenant blade levels stack for purposes of determining the abilities of your animal companion. (143)
- The prestige class Vandalis beastkeeper (*Dra* 130) at level 1 gains the extraordinary ability improved companion or mount. It reads, in part,

  > Levels in Vandalis beastkeeper stack with levels in the class that grants you your animal companion or special mount for the purposes of determining the functional strength and level of that companion or mount. (131)
- The prestige class wavekeeper (*Sto* 76) at level 2 gains the extraordinary ability beast of the sea. It reads, in part,

  > Starting at 2nd level, your animal companion continues to advance. Subtract 1 from your class level and add the result to your effective druid level for determining the abilities of your animal companion. (77)
- The prestige class wild plains outrider (*CAd* 92) at level 1 gains the ability animal companion/special mount. It reads, in part,

  > A wild plains outrider adds his outrider class levels to his effective druid level (his actual druid level or one-half his ranger level) to determine the capabilities of his animal companion. (93)

**Not from the List of Stuff**

- The prestige class halfling outrider (*CW* 38) at level 1 gains the ability mount. It reads, in part,

  > Halfling outrider class levels stack with paladin, druid, and ranger levels for determining the characteristics of a paladin’s mount or an animal companion. (39)
- The prestige class legacy champion (*WoL* 19) at every level *except* 1 and 7 gains the ability class features (seriously, the special ability is named *class features* so it has a class feature called class features). It reads, in part,

  > At each level except 1st and 7th, you gain class features and an increase in effective level as if you had also gained a level in a class to which you belonged before adding the prestige class level. The specific class features you gain include spells per day (and spells known, if applicable), improved chance of turning or destroying undead, metamagic
  >   or item creation feats, bonus feats, monk special abilities, sneak attack progressions, *and so on, depending on the class*. [Emphasis mine.] (19-20).

  Ten levels of the class should increase by 8 the character's level for his animal companion ability among all but the most conservative DMs but, as always, ask.

---

I'm happy to update this based on Comments and my research. As the question asks only for prestige classes, just those'll be listed, despite other animal companion resources being awesome (e.g. the feat Devoted Tracker (*CAd* 108), the alternative class feature urban companion ("*Cityscape*, Part 1: Urban Class Features" [here](https://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/we/20070228a)).

Comment: Thanks! That seems very complete, and just what I needed.

Comment: Also, for what it is worth, in addition to stacking with the animal companion levels of other classes the Beastmaster prestige class from Complete Adventurer also gets a +3 bonus to the level. So a level 1 druid with 1 level in Beastmaster gets a companion equal to a level 5 druid.