# How can a beast heart adept's abilities improve after finishing the class?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, feats, prestige-class, animal-companions

I'm playing a marshal 1/totemist 4/beast heart adept 9. Since I'm nearly done with the prestige class [beast heart adept](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ex/20070209a&page=4), I need some advice:

1. Do any classes continue what beast heart adept started with its monstrous companions?
2. Are there feats or magic items that improve upon what the beast heart adept can already do?

Comment: I edited this a little. Your original first question is already answered [here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/34952/8610), and your original fourth question about the viability of beast heart adept in a high-level environment makes a better standalone question. Given how narrow the two remaining questions are, I think this lone question is now sufficient, but more information about what feats and gear your PC already has and the makeup of his fellow adventurers would allow answers to be much more precise.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I really think this should be further divided into two separate questions, one about classes or prestige classes to continue advancement, and one about non-class methods of improvement.

Comment: @ObliviousSage While I disagree (I think good answers to #1 are negligibly small, #2 occupying the bulk of any answer), that's still a totally fair assessment. However, I'll let the community and the asker decide that rather than pruning the question further myself. (As I have here, I tend to abstain from voting to reopen held or closed questions that I've edited.)

Comment: Yes since beast heart adept is not nore animal companion which is stated in the post you linked

Comment: Won't be the most popular response, but epic progression from the SRD is a possible way of addressing number one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Improving your effective Beast Heart Adept level

There are two classes in the game, **Uncanny Trickster** (Complete Scoundrel) and **Legacy Champion** (Weapons of Legacy) which, as a class feature, advance the class features and effective level of another class.  Although it's sometimes considered cheesy and should definitely be run by your DM, there's nothing explicitly stopping these classes from advancing your effective Beast Heart Adept class level past 10.

Since the abilities granted to your Monstrous Companion occur on specific levels (rather than being derived from a mathematical formula that references your class level), **increasing your effective Beast Heart Adept level past 10 won't typically make your companion any stronger**.  However, by my reading, you can use these classes to counteract the penalties to effective class level incurred by selecting an advanced companion.

For instance, a Ranger 5/Beast Heart Adept 10/Legacy Champion 5 (effective Beast Heart Adept level 14) could select a Wyvern as their companion, and it would still receive Improved Evasion, despite the -4 penalty incurred for Wyvern being an advanced companion choice.

This may not be an efficient use of levels from an optimization standpoint, but to the best of my knowledge, it is the only way to continue advancing your Monstrous Companion class feature with further class levels after finishing Beast Heart Adept.

---

### Improving your companion in other ways

The best way to improve your companion via magic items is to **equip it with magic items**.  Look into:

- Mouthpick weapons (Lords of Madness), which may be wielded via a creature's mouth, and combined with all non-bite natural attacks in a full attack routine.
- Necklace of Natural Attacks (Savage Species), to give your companion's natural attacks magical enhancement.
- Stat-boosting wondrous items, like a Belt of Giant Strength, which magically resize to fit their wearer (even if their wearer is not a shape that one normally associates with, say, belts).

Finally, something that isn't strictly allowed, but that I would allow as a house rule if I were DMing for this character:  See if you can use the **Share Soulmeld** feat (Magic of Incarnum) to grant some of your Totemist goodies to your companion.  Because it's not technically an animal companion, familiar, or mount, this doesn't work as-written, but it can't hurt to ask your DM.